# Understanding a recurrence to solve the Coupon Collector problem?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I recently came across this recurrence for the coupon collector problem:

$$\text{draws}(n) = \text{draws}(n-1) \cdot\dfrac{n}{n-1} + 1$$

where $\text{draws}(n)$ is the expected number of coupons to be drawn to get *all* $n$ unique coupons.

Why is this recurrence true? I would prefer an intuitive approach.

Comment: Was there any nearby exposition?

Comment: @Hurkyl No, just the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, I've figured out the idea behind it. The following argument I give is somewhat nonrigorous and I would treat it with suspicion, but it at least conveys the basic idea that you can then take as a starting point for a search for an argument you can be confident in.

---

To draw $n$ distinct coupons, you must:

- draw one coupon
- draw one of each kind from the remaining $n-1$

The second bullet point is *almost* the coupon collector problem for $n-1$ kinds of coupons; the difference is that a fraction $\frac{1}{n}$ of your draws "don't count" because they were of the same type as the first coupon.

In other words, on average you have to make $\frac{n}{n-1}$ draws to get one more pick at the $n-1$ coupon subproblem. Thus,

$$ \text{draws}(n) = 1 + \frac{n}{n-1} \text{draws}(n-1) $$

Comment: I think this is quite good!

Answer (score 3):

With "draws(n)" you seem to mean the expected number of draws to get all elements, if $n$ have to be collected.

The probability to get an object that is not already drawn, decreases from $\frac{n}{n}=1$ downto $\frac{1}{n}$. So, the expected number of draws needed is $$E_n=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{n}{j}=n\cdot H(n)$$

Therefor we have $$E_{n-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \frac{n-1}{j}$$

This implies $$\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot E_{n-1}=\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{n}{j}$$ hence $$E_n=\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot E_{n-1}+ \frac{n}{n}=\frac{n}{n-1}\cdot E_{n-1}+1$$

Comment: Thanks! But is it possible to arrive at this result intuitively?

Comment: @prakharsingh95 Do you mean the formula for $E_n$ or the recursion for the $E_n$'s ?

Comment: I meant the recursion, like if you know $E_{n-1}$, how do you calculate $E_n$?

Comment: Can you clarify "add an object" and "remove an object"?

Comment: I suspect that my argument is wrong and that the total number only accidently coincides. If we have $10$ objects instead of $9$, after the first draw the probability that we get a different object is $\frac{9}{10}$ instead of $\frac{8}{9}$. This is even higher. I must think again about it ... OK, forget my argument. The probabilities are higher, but we need one more draw. Sorry.

Comment: The probability that we are succesfull in draw $k$, if $n-1$ objects are present, is $\frac{n-k}{n-1}$ ($k=1,\cdots n-1$). The probability that we are succesful in draw $k+1$, if $n$ objects are present, is $\frac{n-k}{n}$ ($k=1,\cdots n-1$). The first draw (with $n$ objects) is the "1" in the recursion. The other probabilities multiply with $\frac{n-1}{n}$, hence the expected numbers of draws multiply with $\frac{n}{n-1}$. I am not sure, whether this is easier than what I did in my answer.

Comment: You should add this to the answer. The key point, as I understand, is that $draws(n-1)$ is the solution with $n-1$ coupons, but we need $draws(n-1,n)$, which is the expected number of coupons needed to be drawn to get unique $n-1$ coupons when $n$ objects are available and first one is not allowed, and they are related by this factor!